# How to handle conditional redirect in react app routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, metronic

I am using a `metronic theme` for my react project and now I am trying to do a conditional redirect based on value from an api. I found a file called `Routes.js` already written and I am trying to change there. This is what it looks like

```
 const [request, setRequest] = useState();
 const [isUserActive, setIsUserActive] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://82 ...")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setRequest(data));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (request) {
      request.isUser=== true
        ? setIsUserActive(true)
        : setIsUserActive(false);
    }
  }, [request]);

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/error" component={ErrorsPage} />

      {!isUserActive ? (
        <Redirect to="error/error-v1" />
      ) : (
        <>
          <Redirect to="/" />
          <Layout>
            <BasePage />
          </Layout>
        </>
      )}
    </Switch>
  );
```

When `isUserActive` is `true`, I want to go to `root` path but if it isn't, I want to go to `error page`. `isUserActive` now logs

```
false 
false 
true
```

But my project is always redirecting to `/error/error-v1` even though the final value is `true`, am I missing something here ?

Comment: `isActive` initial state is false before it is updated by the fetch in the effect. The path "/error" matches as a prefix to "/error/error-v1" so the "logic" after that route is never hit by the `Switch`. It isn't really clear what your `Switch` components are trying to do. Also, only `Route` and `Redirect` components are valid children of `Switch`. Is the `Layout` component what you want rendered as the home (`"/"`) route? Is there a `Router` component somewhere in the hierarchy?

Comment: There are other built in components about router (BasePage, ..) of metronic theme. I thought I just needed to change here. I found the solution anyway by doing as the guy in the answer section said. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to add another state for loading. The reason why is that with the current setup, once the code directs you to the /error endpoint there is no going back and it will always render the error page.

```js
const [request, setRequest] = useState();
// vvv this was added vvv
// vvv this was added vvv
// vvv this was added vvv
const [requestLoading, setRequestLoading] = useState(true);
const [isUserActive, setIsUserActive] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
   fetch("http://82 ...")
     .then((res) => res.json())
     .then((data) => setRequest(data));
 }, []);

 useEffect(() => {
   if (request) {
     // vvv this was added vvv
     // vvv this was added vvv
     // vvv this was added vvv
     setRequestLoading(false);
     request.isUser=== true
       ? setIsUserActive(true)
       : setIsUserActive(false);
   }
 }, [request]);

 return (
   // vvv this conditional rendering was added vvv
   // vvv this conditional rendering was added vvv
   // vvv this conditional rendering was added vvv
   {!requestLoading ? <Switch>
     <Route path="/error" component={ErrorsPage} />

     {!isUserActive ? (
       <Redirect to="error/error-v1" />
     ) : (
       <>
         <Redirect to="/" />
         <Layout>
           <BasePage />
         </Layout>
       </>
     )}
   </Switch> : <div />}
 );
```

For now all this does is render a div if the request is still loading, then it routes you based on the result once its finished

Comment: That's a great way to wait the state to get the final value, thanks for the help !